# How can we import products data in magento2 programmatically

Tags: magento2, products

How can we import products data from third party in magento 2 programmatically ?
We have some feeds for products , categories. We need to store in to magento

Comment: you can create custom script or extension for this to do this.

Comment: you can use the product attributes and then use the attribute code for your csv,

Answer (score 0):

As the first create the `importproducts.php` file inside the script folder in the magento root directory.Then establish the database connection as shown below.

```
<?php
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); 
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include('../app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$app_state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$app_state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$productsData = getProducts();
importSimpleProducts( $productsData , $objectManager );
```

This step reads the products data from the CSV.

```
function getProducts()
{
    $file = 'csv/products.csv';
    $arrResult = array();
    $headers = false;
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    if (empty($handle) === false) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            if (!$headers) {
                $headers[] = $data;
            } else {
                $arrResult[] = $data;
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $arrResult;
}
```

The above function reads the data from the CSV and return the data in an array. The following code iterate through the array and create the products as show above.

```
/*
 * Import Simple Products
 */
function importSimpleProducts( $importProducts, $objectManager ) {

    // Path to media folder        
    $filesystem = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
    $mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    $mediaPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath();

    foreach( $importProducts as $importProduct ) {

        try {  

            $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
            $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
            $product->setAttributeSetId(4);
            $product->setTypeId('simple');
            $product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')); 
            $product->setName($importProduct[1]); 
            $product->setSku($importProduct[3]);
            $product->setWeight($importProduct[16]);
            $product->setStatus(1);
            $category_id= array(30,24);
            $product->setCategoryIds($category_id); 
            $product->setTaxClassId(0); // (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
            $product->setVisibility(4); // catalog and search visibility
            $product->setColor(24);
            $product->setPrice($importProduct[11]) ;
            $product->setCost(1); 
            $product->setMetaTitle($importProduct[1]);
            $product->setMetaKeyword($importProduct[26]);
            $product->setMetaDescription($importProduct[28]);
            $product->setDescription($importProduct[27]);
            $product->setShortDescription($importProduct[27]);

            $product->setStockData(
                array(
                'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, 
                'manage_stock' => 1, // manage stock
                'min_sale_qty' => 1, // Shopping Cart Minimum Qty Allowed 
                'max_sale_qty' => 2, // Shopping Cart Maximum Qty Allowed
                'is_in_stock' => 1, // Stock Availability of product
                'qty' => (int)$importProduct[6]
                )
            );


            $product->save();
            echo "Upload simple product id :: ".$product->getId()."\n";
        }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo 'Something failed for product import ' . $importProduct[1] . PHP_EOL;
        print_r($e);
    }
}   
}
```

Copy the images the media folder and following code set the images as shown below.

```
// Absolute path

    $filesystem = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
    $mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    $mediaPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath();


 $mainImage = $importProduct[9];
// Main Image
    if ($mainImage) {
        $image_directory = $mediaPath . DS . 'data' . DS . $mainImage;
        if (file_exists($image_directory)) {
            $product->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array()))//media gallery initialization
                ->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'), false, false);//assigning image, thumb and small image to media gallery
        } 
        else {
            $image_directory = $mediaPath . 'data' . DS . 'comingsoon.jpg';
            $product->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array()))//media gallery initialization
                ->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'), false, false);
        }
    }

    // additional images
    if ($importProduct[29] != '') {
        $addImages = explode(",", trim($importProduct[29]));
        foreach ($addImages as $additional_image) {
            $image_directory = $mediaPath .DS.'data'.DS. trim($additional_image);
            if (file_exists($image_directory)) {
                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, null, false, false);
            } 
            else {
                $image_directory = $mediaPath . 'data' . DS . 'comingsoon.jpg';
                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, null, false, false);
            }
        }
        echo 'Additional images for product ' . $product->getName() . ' ' . $product->getId() . ' imported successfully' . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

**I hope this will help and I try to cover all aspects**

Comment: this might work, but it will take ages

Comment: After creating this file under script folder how can we execute this file to add products in the system

Comment: @Marius yes you are absolutely correct but I try to give resolution of the problem or query. There might be better way exist

Comment: @VandanaSingh You just need to open Command line go to your file directory and execute the command `php  importproducts.php`

Comment: @MuhammadHusham  Thank you !!  Actually  I have different Csv files for data. In the CSV file products ,categories ,sub categories and product variations this kind of data are available.So can we import all data in to magento system ?

Comment: @Marius, do you have any better option to import products from CSV?

Comment: Using the magento native csv import. If you don't want to upload it manually, you can check what happens under the hood when you upload the csv file and by-pass the upload process and go directly to the processing part.

Comment: Would it not be a more versatile option to create a new module with a console command file that calls a method(s) in the `execute()` that performs the actions from that script. You then have the option to output errors, possible debug info to the console.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <?php 
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include("./app/bootstrap.php");
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
 // add logging capability
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/import-Products.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$eavConfig = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'es_flavour');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
print_r($options);

foreach($options as $option) {
    if($option['label'] == "braambes"){
        $value = $option['value'];
    }
}
    try{
            $simpleProduct = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
            $simpleProduct->setSku('Testing5');
            $simpleProduct->setName('Testing11115');
            // $attributeSetId = $simpleProduct->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
            $simpleProduct->setAttributeSetId(4);
            $simpleProduct->setCategoryIds(array(6));
            $simpleProduct->setDescription('This is for testing');
            $simpleProduct->setStatus(1);
            $simpleProduct->setTypeId('simple');
            $simpleProduct->setTaxClassId(2); // (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
            $simpleProduct->setPrice(500);
            $simpleProduct->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
            $simpleProduct->setVisibility(4);
            $simpleProduct->setUrlKey('Testing445');
            $simpleProduct->setStoreId(1);
            $simpleProduct->setStockData(array(
                'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                'qty' => 100//qty
                    )
            );

            $simpleProduct->setCustomAttribute("es_flavour",$value);

            $simpleProduct->save();
            $simpleProductId = $simpleProduct->getId();
            $simpleProductSku = $simpleProduct->getSku();
            echo "Simple Product ID: " . $simpleProductId . "\n";
    }catch (\Exception $e) {
            //print_r($e->getMessage());
            $logger->info('Error importing product sku: '.$simpleProductSku.'. '.$e->getMessage());
            // continue;
}
?>
```